# Hide Zero Value Balance Row From Report In Ms Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm Working On A Project In Microsoft Access 2010 I'm Facing Some Issue And Can't Understand How To Solve
I Tried Many Methods But Failed

In My Query [TQ]Total Quantity | [STQ]Total Sale Quantity | [RQ:][TQ]-[STQ]Remaining Quantity
I Want To Remove If RQ Remaining Quantity Is 0 Then Not Showing In My Report With "YES" or "NO" Require

Here Is I Attached Screen Shot OF Query & Report

[image]

[image]

Please Anyone can Help Me For This Issue.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand your requirement. Do you want to replace zero with a "No" on your report?

Comment: @KostasK. Hi Thanks For Comment Sir I Want To Hide Zero Value Row From Report

Comment: Set a conditional formatting on the control, when value = 0 change foreground to white.

Comment: Sir I'm Using MS Access After 8 Years I Have Not Remembered Any thing Only Trying To Do Work With Search & Help Please Can You Explain Me More

Comment: Not much to explain, I cannot post screenshots. Do a google search how to set conditional formatting. Plenty of examples available.

Comment: Ok Sir thank you let me try

Comment: Can I remove Complete Row From Display?

Comment: No, but you can change the expression on the query to return NULL if the difference is zero:  `IIF([TQ]-[STQ]>0,[TQ]-[STQ],NULL) AS [RQ]`.

Comment: Sir Thank You Soooo much I Have Solve The Problem But Only One Problem Can I Use Thie Code With Yes Or No Value <[contdetails]![Quantity] if I Type Yes Then This Criteria Work If I Leave Blank Then By Pass This.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No formula is needed. Just apply this to the Format property of the textbox RQ in your report:

```
0,\-0,""
```

or, if semicolon is your local separator:

```
0;\-0;""
```